# How to search in ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-1.4

I am new to django, and I am trying to make a query in a Many to many field.
an example of my query:

in the Models I have

```
class Line(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name of line", max_length=50, blank=True)


class Cross(models.Model):
    lines = models.ManyToManyField(Line, verbose_name="Lines crossed")
    date = models.DateField('Cross Date', null=True, blank=False)
```

I am making a search querying all the crosses that have certain lines.
I mean the query in the search box will look like: line_1, line_2, line_3 
and the result will be all the crosses that have all the lines (line_1, line2, line_3)

I don't know how should the filter condition be!

```
    all_crosses = Cross.objects.all().filter(???)
```

The view code:

```
def inventory(request):

if request.method == "POST":

    if 'btn_search' in request.POST:

        if 'search_by_lines' in request.POST:
            lines_query = request.POST['search_by_lines']
            queried_lines = split_query(lines_query, ',')

            query = [Q(lines__name=l) for l in queried_lines]
            print(query)
            result = Cross.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, query))
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do:

```
crosses = Cross.objects.filter(lines__name__in=['line_1', 'line_2', 'line_3'])
```

for any of the three values. If you're looking for *all* of the values that match, you'll need to use a Q object:

```
from django.db.models import Q

crosses = Cross.objects.filter(
    Q(lines__name='line_1') &
    Q(lines__name='line_2') &
    Q(lines__name='line_3')
)
```

There is at least one other approach you can use, which would be chaining filters:

```
Cross.objects.filter(lines__name='line_1')
    .filter(lines_name='line_2')
    .filter(lines__name='line_3')
```

If you need to dynamically construct the `Q` objects, and assuming the "name" value is what you're posting:

```
import operator

lines = [Q(line__name='{}'.format(line)) for line in request.POST.getlist('lines')]
crosses = Cross.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, lines))
```

---

### [Update]

Turns out, I was dead wrong. I tried a couple of different ways of querying `Cross` objects where the value of `lines` matched all of the items searched. `Q` objects, annotations of counts on the number of objects contained... nothing worked as expected.

In the end, I ended up matching `cross.lines` as a list to the list of values posted.

In short, the search view I created matched in this fashion:

```
results = []
posted_lines = []
search_by_lines = 'search_by_lines' in request.POST.keys()
crosses = Cross.objects.all().prefetch_related('lines')

if request.method == 'POST' and search_by_lines:
    posted_lines = request.POST.getlist('line')

    for cross in crosses:
        if list(cross.lines.values_list('name', flat=True)) == posted_lines:
            results.append(cross)

return render(request, 'search.html', {'lines': lines, 'results': results,
    'posted_lines': posted_lines})
```

What I would probably do in this case is add a column on the `Cross` model to keep a comma separated list of the primary keys of the related `lines` values, which you could keep in sync via a post_save signal.

With the additional field, you could query directly against the "line" values without joins.

Comment: I'm not sure about OP's question, but sounds like he wants all `Cross` that contains ALL 3 lines.

Comment: I think you're correct. I'll need to update my answer

Comment: Yea that's right
I want every cross that has all the queried lines

Comment: @نوارمكيس I've updated the sample code for you. My preference in this case would be to use `Q` objects, simply because I think it's the most readable.

Comment: @Brandon your first code should work, but not in every database.

Comment: @Gocht The first query would get a `Cross` even if it only had one line with a name of 'line_1', not if **all** of the lines match.

Comment: Great, Thanks,  but I don't have a prior knowledge of the query
So I don't know how many lines the user might ask for
Shall I use a For loop or is there something inDjango does it?

Comment: I'd like test this further but I get `NotSupportedError: (1235, "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'")` I'll be waitching this.

Comment: @نوارمكيس Meaning... the possible `line` values are coming in via GET parameters, or a form POST?

Comment: Via POST
When the user presses the search button

Comment: @نوارمكيس Added an example for you.

Comment: @Brandon 
The query is not working.
I tried the or operator and it used only the first line name
I tried one line only it worked
But in case of more than one line with and operator it gives no result

Comment: You'll need to add your view code, or ask a separate question.

Comment: What is the value of `queried_lines` ?

Comment: It represents the names of the lines that was entered in the search box 
The function split_query splits the names for after the ' , ' and returns an arrays contains the lines names

Comment: I can see from the code what it represents. I want the actual value returned after a POST please.

Comment: the search query that came in the POST :  line_1, line_2
the queried_lines after the splitting: ['line_1', 'line_2']

Comment: I made a very small tweak to the `lines = [. . .]` value in my example code.

Comment: I am sorry but now it can't find any result even when querying one line

Comment: I'm out of time for the moment, but I'll try to work up an example for you later.